# Move specified sub folders base on name lengh in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I made one little tool for my work, I have main folder like:

C:\TEMP

And there contain some sub folders there:
......
C:\TEMP\EN
C:\TEMP\DE
C:\TEMP\JA
....
C:\TEMP\ABC
C:\TEMP\xxx
.....

I`d like to move all the sub folders into "Archive" which sub folder name length are two.

Result:
C:\TEMP\Archive\EN
C:\TEMP\Archive\DE
C:\TEMP\Archive\JA

Can you please give some ideas how can i filter the folder name with the length? And so I can do next step action in the loop.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
forfiles /p "c:\temp" /m "??" /c "cmd /c if @isdir==TRUE move @path c:\temp\archive"
```